# Same design for android and iOS in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

How can I have same design on iOS as it is for android in Xamarin.forms? For android I get icon of the app at the top left corner which seems to be missing on the iOS app. Any way to make the design same as android?

Comment: Please clarify which icon you are referring to and for what implementation. I think you are talking about the icon that appears when using NavigationPage - is this correct?

Comment: You can remove the app icon on Android, which is probably much easier than adding it on iOS.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for the suggestion. I think I should take your advice. ;-)